# devtools::install_github error: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT - The certification chain was issued by an entity that is unreliable

Tags: r, curl, certificate, devtools

I am trying to install an package from **behind a corporate (fire)wall** using `devtools`:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("aryoda/tryCatchLog")
```

I get an error message:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:   schannel:
next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325)
- The certification chain was issued by an entity that is unreliable.
```

The reason seems to be the used `curl` package which produces the same error with:

```
library(curl)
curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://httpbin.org/get")
```

How can I fix this?

PS: I am using MS Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce

Comment: It seems like `devtools` is using `curl` which uses `libcurl` which uses `Schannel` (Microsofts native TLS engine) which uses the certificates that are built into Windows (instead of any CA cert bundle in R/etc/ or R/library/curl/). Damn difficult to diagnose the problems... I am still investigating more details...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

The internet connection does only work within `curl` if you set the correct HTTPS_PROXY:

```
# insert your correct domain name and IP port here
Sys.setenv(https_proxy = "http://httpproxy.mycompany.com:1234")
```

This `devtools` issue comment did help me:
https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1610#issuecomment-333344548

**Update 1:**

This is a generic solution to set the HTTP(S)_PROXY in R:

```
requires(curl)
requires(devtools)

proxy <- curl::ie_get_proxy_for_url("https://www.qwant.com/")

Sys.setenv(https_proxy=proxy)
# Sys.setenv(http_proxy=proxy)  # you could also set an HTTP proxy

devtools::install_github("aryoda/tryCatchLog") # should work now
```

You could add this line to your `Rprofile.site` file (in `R/etc` folder)